# How to wrap text in the formula field of calculated columns?

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have a long formula which I put into the formula field in the calculated column. However, in Sharepoint 2013, the text in formula field is not wrapped. Is there anyway to make the text wrapped in this case?

[image: Formula Field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpreted your question in two different ways:

.

## 1 - output a linebreak in a View

You have 2 options in SharePoint 2013 to format **output** of the Calculated Column

### Calculated Column with HTML

You can make a Calculated Column output as HTML/JavaScript by setting the datatype to Number.
Change your Formula to include an HTML BReak and you are done

```
=TRIM(LastName)&"<br>"&TRIM(FirstName)
```

**Pros**

- Works everwhere the Column is displayed
- Also works in SharePoint 2010

**Cons**

- Only works in Views
- The bare HTML is displayed in other places like Forms, Alerts

Full detailed explanation of using HTML & JavaScript in a Calculated Column at http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

### Client Side Rendering of a Column

Since SharePoint 2013 you can use CSR and JSlink to completely change the user interface.

*CSR* is your JavaScript override which make all the changes, *JSlink* is the method where you have to tell every View, Form, Field, Webpart which CSR file it has to use.

For your simple linebreak this 'simple' Javascript file (saved in ~site/Style Library/myCSR.js) will do:

```
(function () {
    var CSRcontext = {};
    CSRcontext.Templates = {};
    CSRcontext.Templates.Fields = {
        "firstName": {
            "View": myCSRTemplate
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(CSRcontext);
})();
function myCSRTemplate(ctx, CurrentFieldSchema, CurrentItem, ListSchema) {
    var firstName = CurrentItem[CurrentFieldSchema['firstName']].trim();
    var lastName = CurrentItem[CurrentFieldSchema['lastName']].trim();
    return firstName + "<BR>" + lastName;
}
```

**And** you have to assign the JSLink path ~site/Style Library/myCSR.js to **every* View you want this executed.

The **Major** drawback is you also (unlike the first Formula option) have to include *firstName* and *lastName* in the View, otherwise those Columns are not available in the CSR file.
(You can ofcourse do the work in the Calculated Column like you do now then use CSR to make it output as HTML)

## 2 - You want line breaks in the Formula textarea

I reread you question..

If you mean you want to wrap the text **inside** the TextArea while editting you have several options:

#### switch to Chrome Browser

In Chrome TextArea has a resize handle.

#### Assign CSS to the textarea

If you can get into your MasterPage (or other CSS file) just add:

```
#onetidIODefTextValue1{
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Again, easier on Chrome, where you can use the [StyleBot plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) to apply this CSS on the fly.

Or you can create your own Bookmarklet (a Favorite button in your browser which execute JavaScript).
Goto [MrColes BookMarklet Creator](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) and paste the script:

```
document.getElementById('onetidIODefTextValue1').style.whiteSpace="pre";
```

Drag the blue (this link) to your Favourites bar (and rename it)

Now on any Formula page you can execute the BookMarklet.

#### CalcMaster

If you are comfortable adding a Bookmarklet with more JavaScript.

I have written a small 'CalcMaster' bookmarklet which hooks into the formula-editor and does a save of the Formula on every keypress; giving immediate feedback.
Recently published a first version on GitHub:

https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster